# Tutorial page /environment/rundebug/nodejs.md-request guidance unable to execute. Ref: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/rundebug/nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to explore this tutorial (https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/rundebug/nodejs) and I've completed all the steps as given. When debug run is executed, i get to see below error in VScode, in spite of having start.js in application root folder

Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module 'D:\vbengg\forge-autodesk\forgenodesample\start.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at  (internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Kindly share your launch.json file